# MongoDB connections keep increasing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin, node-mongodb-native

I keep hitting my connection limit, but http traffic has remained consistent. I used MMS to profile my mongod process and saw that the number of connections keeps rising:

[image: mongod connections]

I'm using the mongoskin wrapper for Node.js (Express). I have a piece of custom route middleware that connects to the mongo db before executing other routes:

```
var _connect = function(req, res, next) {
  res.db = mongoskin.db(_us.sprintf(
    '%s:%s@localhost:27017/%s?auto_reconnect',
    app.set('mongoDbUser'),
    app.set('mongoDbPw'),
    app.set('mongoDb')
  ));
  next();
};
```

Am I doing something wrong? How should I be opening and closing connections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) is a wrapper for the [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver so options for the underlying native driver still apply.

Some suggestions to reduce the number of connections used:

1. Open your connection before starting the application (you don't want to open a connection in each request):

   ```
    var db = new mongoskin.db(...) 
    db.open(function(err, db) { 
        // Application logic
    })
   ```
2. Adjust the node-mongo-native [connection poolSize](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/database.md#server-options). Connection pooling allows a set of connections to be shared in your application rather than always opening new connections.  The default poolSize is 1 in older drivers and 5 as of the node-mongo-native 1.1.4 driver which was released Aug 16, 2012.

   So you could try something like:

   ```
    var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
    var serverOptions = {
        'auto_reconnect': true,
        'poolSize': 5
    };
    var db = mongoskin.db('localhost:27017/test', serverOptions);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Stennie. I connected to the db in each of my Express config sections, then set res.db = app.set('mongoConn') in my first custom middleware. Worked perfectly.